# Поиск пользователей по заданным полям

Tags: drupal, search

Сделал страницу регистрации, в которой пользователь вводит нужные мне поля. Пытаюсь сделать поиск по этим полям, использую модуль поиска апи, но никак не могу найти, где мне создавать поля поиска, например: пользователь при регистрации указывает, что он курит, в поиске должна быть строчка "курение" - да, нет (чекбокс). Вот никак не могу придумать, как это сделать.

Comment: Вам нужен именно поиск или фильтрация по вашим поля?
То, что вы описали, больше смахивает на фильтр по полям. С этим отлично справляется views.

Answer (score 1):

Устанавливаете Search API, устанавливаете к нему бекенд, далее в зависимости от бекенда создаёте индекс, по этому индексу строите вьюху